# How to specify a JPA named parameter surrounded by wildcards?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, named-parameters

How would I specify a JPA query like:

```
Query q = 
  em.createQuery(
    "SELECT x FROM org.SomeTable x WHERE x.someString LIKE '%:someSymbol%'"
  );
```

followed by:

```
q.setParameter("someSymbol", "someSubstring");
```

and not triggering a

```
org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: could not locate named parameter [id]
```

Much appreciated!

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144235/jpa-hibernate-native-queries-do-not-recognize-parameters

Comment: I'm trying to avoid doing a native query, rather I'm hoping that it is somehow possible in JPA to use named parameters with 'LIKE' and wildcards.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

How about

```
Query q = 
  em.createQuery(
    "SELECT x FROM org.SomeTable x WHERE x.someString LIKE :someSymbol"
);
q.setParameter("someSymbol", "%someSubstring%");
```

I'm pretty sure I once solved your problem like that.

Comment: Seems like when I go from raw SQL to JPA, I "think backwards" or something, thanks for straightening me out @musiKk.

Comment: Seems to work also well with positional parameters such as in the following: `@NamedQuery(name = User.BY_USERNAME, query = "SELECT e from User AS e where e.USERNAME like CONCAT('%', ?1, '%')")`

Answer (score 67):

For reference, you could also use CONCAT:

```
like CONCAT('%', :someSymbol, '%')
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. It helps. +1

Comment: This should be an accepted solution. It works also in frameworks like sprint-data where query can be declared using @Query annotation.

Comment: Or `CONCAT('%', CONCAT(:someSymbol, '%'))` for Oracle SQL

Answer (score 4):

query.setParameter(someSymbol, "%" + someSymbol+ "%");