# to put some MYSQL to a named query

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa, named-query

i need to translate some MySQL code to a JPA named query

example

> select * from movies where title like '%matrix%'

would my gues it would

> ```
> @NamedQuery(name = "Movies.findMoviePart", query = "SELECT c FROM Movies c  where c.title  LIKE '% :title %'")})
> be but it has some errors
> ```

org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: could not locate named parameter [title]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: could not locate named parameter [title]

code in dao impl

> @Override     public List getAllPartMovie(String title) {
>         TypedQuery query =
>                   entityManager.createNamedQuery("Movies.findMoviePart", Movies.class);
>           query.setParameter("title", title);
>           try {
>               return query.getResultList();
>           } catch (NoResultException ex) { // geen record gevonden
>               return null;
>           }

tanks for your help guys

Answer (score 0):

Don't add the % to the query, add them to the parameter in your query:

```
query.setParameter("title", "%" + value + "%");
```

Another question almost identical to yours: [How to specify a JPA named parameter surrounded by wildcards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5983321/how-to-specify-a-jpa-named-parameter-surrounded-by-wildcards)