# Hibernate method throwing 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException'

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a query in hibernate to get list of items as below:

```
public List<ToDo> getItemsWithStatus(String status) {
    TypedQuery<ToDo> query = em.createQuery(
            "SELECT u FROM TODO u WHERE u.status LIKE :status ORDER BY u.id", ToDo.class);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

But while executing the method, I'm getting this exception:

> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: TODO is not mapped [SELECT u FROM TODO u WHERE u.status LIKE :status ORDER BY u.id]

Thanks
Jithesh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your entity class is named `ToDo`, but in your JPQL you are using `TODO` (notice the difference in cases).

Comment: I have updated the JPQL, and successfully created the query object. But while executing the query getting the below exception
org.hibernate.QueryException: Not all named parameters have been set: [status] [SELECT u FROM ToDo u WHERE u.status LIKE :status ORDER BY u.id]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5983321/how-to-specify-a-jpa-named-parameter-surrounded-by-wildcards