# jpa select can not work

Tags: java, jpa, ejb-3.0

```
select id,name,amount,sort 
from 
(select id,name,amount,sort,gift_id,count(gift_id) 
from 
(select * from t_lpw_gift g join t_lpw_dianxin_gift d on g.id=d.gift_id) 
group by gift_id,id,name,amount,sort order by count(gift_id) desc) 
where rownum <=5;
```

how to use jpa createNativeQuery to select,database is oracle

table:

```
SQL> desc t_lpw_gift;
Name   Type         Nullable Default Comments 
------ ------------ -------- ------- -------- 
ID     INTEGER                                
NAME   VARCHAR2(32)                           
PRICE  NUMBER                                 
AMOUNT INTEGER                                
SORT   VARCHAR2(32) Y                         

SQL> desc t_lpw_dianxin_gift;
Name        Type    Nullable Default Comments 
----------- ------- -------- ------- -------- 
GIFT_ID     INTEGER                           
DIANXIN_ID  INTEGER                           
GIFT_NUMBER INTEGER Y
```

return Entity is t_lpw_gift

```
public List<Gift> getHotGifts(int topHotGiftsNum) {
    String sql = "select id,name,amount,sort from (select id,name,amount,sort,gift_id,count(gift_id) from (select * from t_lpw_gift g join t_lpw_dianxin_gift d on g.id=d.gift_id) group by gift_id,id,name,amount,sort order by count(gift_id) desc) where rownum <= :topHotGiftsNum";
return (List<Gift>)em.createNativeQuery(sql,Gift.class).setParameter("topHotGiftsNum", topHotGiftsNum).getResultList();
}
```

18:55:11,473 WARN  [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] SQL Error: 17006, SQLState: 99999
18:55:12,992 ERROR [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] 列名无效()

Comment: When you execute the SQL directly against the database (not through JPA), does it work?

Comment: are you getting invalid column name exception in your stacktrace ?

Comment: it seems that you have an invalid column name. so check the column names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On native SQL parameters in JPA, you need to use a positional parameter instead of a named parameter.  Named parameters are not supported according to the spec.

So, change `:topHotGiftsNum` to `?1`, and `setParameter(1, topHotGiftsNum)`.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144235/jpa-hibernate-native-queries-do-not-recognize-parameters)

Edit: OK, that wasn't it.  This should be it: the select clause is missing some property from the entity, or one of the columns in the select clause is mis-typed.  Your select clause needs to include all of the columns from the entity, without any difference in names.  As per [this thread from Hibernate forums](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=947598&start=30).

Answer (score 0):

The comment of @Kent make me search the keywords:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/reservewords.htm

It seems that **NAME** might be the culprit as reserved word. Was not aware of that (always using SURNAME and such). *However NAME should be allowable. Try quoting NAME and SORT.*