# Saying position beyond number of declared ordinal parameters

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to perform a native/raw mysql query using hibernate, I have this:

```
 sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(
       "update table1 set someCounter = someCounter + 1 where id = ?")
     .setParameter(1, someId)
     .executeUpdate();
```

I'm getting the error:

```
threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is
      org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: Position beyond number of declared ordinal
      parameters. Remember that ordinal parameters are 1-based! Position: 2] 
      with root cause
      org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: Position beyond number of declared ordinal
      parameters. Remember that ordinal parameters are 1-based! Position: 2
```

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use index as `0` since the parameter index start from  `0`.

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
  .createSQLQuery("update table1 set someCounter = someCounter + 1 where id = ?")
  .setParameter(0, someId)
  .executeUpdate();
```

Since you are using Hibernate, you can use the named parameter as well i.e.

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
  .createSQLQuery("update table1 set someCounter = someCounter + 1 where id = :id")
  .setParameter("id", someId)
  .executeUpdate();
```

Comment: The use of named parameters applies to the Java Persistence query language, and is not defined for native queries.

Comment: My Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144235/jpa-hibernate-native-queries-do-not-recognize-parameters

Comment: @kmb385: That is true for JPA. Please read this for Hibernate: [**Hibernate Native SQL**](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#d0e13930) --> `Native SQL queries support positional as well as named parameters`. This supports the named parameter. Please look at the very first example.

Comment: But the exception message itself is saying that it's 1-based.

Comment: That is in conflict with the JavaDoc, checkout the Java Doc http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html#setParameter%28int,%20java.lang.Object%29

Comment: @YogendraSingh just read yourlink, I was getting Hibernate and JPA confused.

Comment: @kmb385: Right next to that, `Query setParameter(String name, Object val) throws HibernateException` is also there.

Comment: @BheshGurung: Not sure if I understand your input. Either go through the URL or the javadoc. It says clearly, -`-the position of the parameter in the query string, numbered from **0**.`

Comment: @YogendraSingh: It's correct on according to the docs. But I meant the exception message in the OP.

Comment: @BheshGurung I know thats what I'm saying the javadoc and the exception conflict each other.  I guess the source code would be the only way to solve this, not sure if I want to get that indepth.

Comment: @BheshGurung I was curious and decided to checkout the source code, it appears that it is zero based.  Please see my updated post.

Comment: http://shervinasgari.blogspot.com/2011/01/remember-that-ordinal-parameters-are-1.html may be helpful

Comment: I googled the warning "Positional parameter are considered deprecated; use named parameters or JPA-style positional parameters instead." and then ran into this problem. Best to use named parameters to avoid this confusion.

Answer (score 4):

The parameters use a zero based index. Try:

```
 sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery("update table1 set someCounter = someCounter + 1 where id = ?")
                .setParameter(0, someId)
                .executeUpdate();
```

The current Hibernate JavaDocs also specify that setPosition relies on zero based indexing for positional parameters.  http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html#setParameter%28int,%20java.lang.Object%29

```
setParameter

Query setParameter(int position,
                   Object val)
                   throws HibernateException

    Bind a value to a JDBC-style query parameter. The Hibernate type of the parameter is first detected via the usage/position in the query and if not sufficient secondly guessed from the class of the given object.

    Parameters:
        position - the position of the parameter in the query string, numbered from 0.
        val - the non-null parameter value 
    Throws:
        HibernateException - if no type could be determined
```

Check the out the parameters section of this document: https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Web_Server/1.0/html/Hibernate_Core_Reference_Guide/querysql.html#id3043464

There has been some discussion regarding whether the setParameter() method is zero based or one based.  This confusion is due to the exception received by the poster noting that parameters are 1 based, while the JavaDoc states that they are zero based.  I analyzed the Hibernate source code and believe that they are in fact zero based.  Assuming that I checked the right class, the underlying code uses a list to store the parameter bind values, which would imply that the setParameter method is in fact zero based.  Checkout the source code for yourself:  https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/internal/AbstractQueryImpl.java

Answer (score 0):

`Positional` parameters start from `0` not `1`

> Native SQL queries support positional as well as named parameters:

update your query by passing 0 instead of 1 in `setParameter(1, someId)`

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery("update table1 set someCounter = someCounter + 1 where id = ?")
                .setParameter(0, someId)
                .executeUpdate();
```

resource [parameters](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html)

Answer (score 0):

To those of you who couldn't resolve based on the solution above, it seems like at times hibernate (depending on the version, I'm using 3) actually gives you the wrong error, for example the issue could be present if you make a syntax error in the hibernate q language:

```
find("from Student s where s.id = :id")
```

change it to this:

```
find("from Student s where s.id = ?")
```

actually resolved that issue.  I guess my main point is that you should also look at your syntax for the issue bc it seems hibernate can incorrectly label this exception.