# How to use a dynamic parameter in a IN clause of a JPA named query?

Tags: sql, oracle, jpa, oracle11g

my problem is about this kind of query :

```
select * from SOMETABLE where SOMEFIELD in ('STRING1','STRING2');
```

the previous code works fine within Sql Developer.
The same static query also works fine and returns me a few results;

```
Query nativeQuery = em.createNativeQuery(thePreviousQuery,new someResultSet());
return nativeQuery.getResultList();
```

But when I try to parameterize this, I encounter a problem.

```
final String parameterizedQuery = "select * from SOMETABLE where SOMEFIELD in (?selectedValues)";
Query nativeQuery = em.createNativeQuery(parameterizedQuery ,new someResultSet());
nativeQuery.setParameter("selectedValues","'STRING1','STRING2'");
return nativeQuery.getResultList();
```

I got no result (but no error in console). 
And when I look at the log, I see such a thing :

```
select * from SOMETABLE where SOMEFIELD in (?)
bind => [STRING1,STRING2]
```

I also tried to use no quotes (with similar result), or non ordered parameter (:selectedValues), which leads to such an error :

```
SQL Error: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1
```

I enventually tried to had the parentheses set directly in the parameter, instead of the query, but this didn't work either...

I could build my query at runtime, to match the first (working) case, but I'd rather do it the proper way; thus, if anyone has an idea, I'll read them with great interest!

FYI  :
JPA version 1.0
Oracle 11G

Answer (score 47, accepted):

JPA support the use of a collection as a list literal parameter only in JPQL queries, not in native queries. Some JPA providers support it as a proprietary feature, but it's not part of the JPA specification (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/3145275/1285097).

Named parameters in native queries also aren't part of the JPA specification. Their behavior depends on the persistence provider and/or the JDBC driver.

Hibernate with the JDBC driver for Oracle support both of these features.

```
List<String> selectedValues = Arrays.asList("STRING1", "STRING2");
final String parameterizedQuery = "select * from SOMETABLE where SOMEFIELD in (:selectedValues)";
return em.createNativeQuery(parameterizedQuery)
         .setParameter("selectedValues", selectedValues)
         .getResultList();
```

Comment: Marc-André, thank you for pointing out the problem. Now I realize I'll have to either use hibernate -I won't be allowed to do that I fear- or perform a basic concatenation. Thanks anyway!

Comment: From what I know, the best practice would be to dynamically add to the query a ? parameter for each of the elements in the list, then set each parameter individually. This allows Oracle to use its cache when the query is used many times with the same number of elements.

Comment: The parameter name must be `#selectedValues` for Native queries and not `:selectedValues` with EclipseLink JPA.

Comment: Hibernate with the jTDS JDBC driver for MSSQL also supports lists as parameters for native queries

Answer (score 3):

Instead of:

```
nativeQuery.setParameter("selectedValues", params);
```

I had to use:

```
nativeQuery.setParameterList("selectedValues", params);
```

Comment: Where does `setParameterList` method come from?

Comment: See https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#setParameterList(java.lang.String, java.util.Collection)

Comment: `setParameterList` is a Hibernate specific feature and not available in standard JPA

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me in derby. parameter without "()".

```
List<String> selectedValues = Arrays.asList("STRING1", "STRING2");
final String parameterizedQuery = "select * from SOMETABLE where SOMEFIELD in 
:selectedValues";
return em.createNativeQuery(parameterizedQuery)
         .setParameter("selectedValues", selectedValues)
         .getResultList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace this:

```
nativeQuery.setParameter("selectedValues","'STRING1','STRING2'");
```

with

```
List<String> params;
nativeQuery.setParameter("selectedValues",params);
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer.  Though, I forgot to mention I had tried this too, srry : error 17004 => invalid column type. The bind looks like this : bind => [[STRING1,STRING2]]

Answer (score -1):

I also faced the same issue.
This is what I did:

```
List<String> sample = new ArrayList<String>();
sample.add("sample1");
sample.add("sample2");
```

And now you, can set the sample in `params`.