# Can @Query annotation in Spring Data JPA take in a list of enums?

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I've been trying to figure out how to take an input of a list of enums for my sql query. This is what it looks like:

```
@Query(value = "Select * from employees where city in :cities", nativeQuery = true)
List<Employee> findByCities(@Param("cities") List<City> cities);
```

I understand that for simple queries we can rely on the JPA Criteria API but I want to know if I can actually do it this way instead. Because if so, i can create more complicated queries (such as joins with another table) if I could have this flexibility of specifying the list.

Comment: `@Query` is not in "JPA". It is in "Spring Data JPA" (!= JPA API). That aside you are using SQL there nothing else, so the question should be directed at JDBC really

Answer (score 4):

Yes spring-data-jpa's `@Query` can take a list of `enums`.

This is my repository method

```
@Query("Select u from User u where u.userType in :types")
List<User> findByType(@Param("types") List<UserType> types);
```

This is my repository call

```
userRepository.findByType(Arrays.asList(AppConstant.UserType.PRINCIPLE)))
```

And this is the query logs

```
SELECT user0_.id           AS id1_12_, 
       user0_.date_created AS date_created2_12_, 
       ...
       ...
FROM   users user0_ 
WHERE  user0_.user_type IN ( ? )
```

Hope this helps.

**PS:** I tested this in my local machine with positive results.

---

**Update 1**

The same doesn't work with `nativeQuery=true`. I tested it on my local system and it doesn't seem to be working with native queries. However with JPQL it works fine as mentioned in the above answer.

May be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21494273/3094731) answer will help.