# strange behavior [Spring boot upgrade 2.2.2]Getting java.lang.NullPointerException: null at org.hibernate.loader.custom.sql.NamedParamBinder.bind

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, hibernate-5.x

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.sql.NamedParamBinder.bind(NamedParamBinder.java:34)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.bindParameterValues(CustomLoader.java:475)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.bindPreparedStatement(Loader.java:2169)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:2146)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2078)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2056)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:953)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2887)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2869)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2701)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2696)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:2142)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.list(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:1163)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doList(NativeQueryImpl.java:173)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1533)
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:409)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy292.getResultList(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:126)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:88)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:154)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:142)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor$QueryMethodInvoker.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:195)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:152)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:130)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:367)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:149)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
```

I get above error after upgrading Spring Boot from **1.5.x** to **2.2.2**. I believe this has upgraded the Hibernate version too, and that might cause above error. I'm not sure if this is a bug in Hibernate

Should I **downgrade** my Hibernate version by specifying in gradle? Rather then using the default one which **Spring Boot 2.2.2** provides?

Is it a defect in Hibernate 5.x?

The program start successfully. It gives the error when the program tries to execute the native query; syntax looks like below

```
    @Query(value = " SELECT ds.* FROM DocumentSimilarity AS ds INNER JOIN CompanyDocumentInfo AS hi ON hi.companyDocumentInfoID = ds.companyDocumentInfoID AND hi.isDeleted=:isDeleted AND hi.siteID=:siteID AND hi.clientID=:clientID  " +
            "WHERE        (ds.processStatus =:documentProcessStatus) AND (hi.processStatus =:similarityProcessStatus) AND (hi.excelProcessStatus in:eXcelProcessStatus) order by ds.modifiedDate /*#pageable*/", countQuery = "select count(modifiedDate) from DocumentSimilarity order by modifiedDate /*#pageable*/ ", nativeQuery = true)
    List<DocumentSimilarity> getSimilarityRecordForExcel(@Param("clientID") int clientID, @Param("siteID") String siteID, @Param("documentProcessStatus") String documentProcessStatus, @Param("isDeleted") int isDeleted, @Param("eXcelProcessStatus") List<String> excelProcessStatus, @Param("similarityProcessStatus") String similarityProcessStatus, Pageable pageable);
```

**Findings**

When it tries to execute below

```
final TypedValue typedValue = qp.getNamedParameters().get( name );
typedValue.getType().nullSafeSet( statement, typedValue.getValue(), position, session );
```

**typedValue is null**, name ="eXcelProcessStatus"

I have correctly spelled **eXcelProcessStatus** as this is in database table and in my Entity class

Below is the value in

```
qp.getNamedParameters()

{documentProcessStatus=PROCESSED, clientID=1, isDeleted=0, similarityProcessStatus=NOPROCESS, siteID=3}
```

It does not contain **`eXcelProcessStatus`**, I'm not sure if this has something to do with X (uppercase) in **`eXcelProcessStatus`**

**More findings.**

I have also tried lowering X in `@param(name=excelProcessStatus)`, but I still get the same error.

**Hibernate versions** :
hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar
hibernate-validator-6.1.5.Final.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-5.1.0.Final.jar
hibernate-c3p0-5.4.21.Final.jar

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @AdilOoze i am sorry didn't you get the trace and the details that i added.
Just don't answer randomly

Comment: When do you get that exception? Does not the program run at start or it gives the error when you do sth. specific? Please tell the steps to reproduce the error

Comment: @OnurBaştürk Yes the program starts I am adding the details in question

Comment: What is the exact Hibernate version? What are the values of the parameters when the exception is thrown? Can you debug it in your IDE - put a breakpoint on `NamedParamBinder.bind(NamedParamBinder.java:34)` and see on which parameter does it throw the exception?

Comment: @AdamMichalik already did that debugging.
Added some findings on the question. -Thanks

Comment: I see multiple people report that passing list parameters to native queries only works for some combination of JPA library and DB driver. See these questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21484176/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6277807/

Comment: @AdamMichalik can be....
Nevertheless i have added the answer which is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is due to the the upgrade but doing following changes in the query ( which is a gigantic change ) [space]

instead of

`(hi.excelProcessStatus in:eXcelProcessStatus)`

doing this
`(hi.excelProcessStatus in: eXcelProcessStatus)`

has solved the problem. Issue seems to be with just **[space]**.

Writing method like this

```
@Query(value = " SELECT ds.* FROM DocumentSimilarity AS ds INNER JOIN CompanyDocumentInfo AS hi ON hi.companyDocumentInfoID = ds.companyDocumentInfoID AND hi.isDeleted=:isDeleted AND hi.siteID=:siteID AND hi.clientID=:clientID  " +
            "WHERE        (ds.processStatus =:documentProcessStatus) AND (hi.processStatus =:similarityProcessStatus) AND (hi.excelProcessStatus in: eXcelProcessStatus) order by ds.modifiedDate /*#pageable*/", countQuery = "select count(modifiedDate) from DocumentSimilarity order by modifiedDate /*#pageable*/ ", nativeQuery = true)
    List<DocumentSimilarity> getSimilarityRecordForExcel(@Param("clientID") int clientID, @Param("siteID") String siteID, @Param("documentProcessStatus") String documentProcessStatus, @Param("isDeleted") int isDeleted, @Param("eXcelProcessStatus") List<String> excelProcessStatus, @Param("similarityProcessStatus") String similarityProcessStatus, Pageable pageable);
```