# Exception while passing a list to javax.persistent.query object

Tags: sql, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I have query

```
"SELECT I.INDIVIDUAL_CASE_ID,D.ASSISTER_ID,I.FIRSTNAME,I.LASTNAME,D.LAST_UPDATE_TIMESTAMP,I.ELIGIBILITY_STATUS,I.INDIVIDUAL_CASE_ID," +
               "I.NUMBEROFHOUSEHOLDMEMBERS,I.HOUSEHOLD_INCOME FROM  EXTERNAL_INDIVIDUAL I, EE_DESIGNATE_ASSISTERS D " +
               "WHERE I.INDIVIDUAL_CASE_ID = D.INDIVIDUAL_ID AND D.ASSISTER_ID=:assisterId AND D.INDIVIDUAL_ID IN (:individualIds)";
```

I am passing the parameter like

```
query = em.createNativeQuery(queryStr);
query.setParameter("assisterId", assisterId);
query.setParameter("individualIds",indvIdList);
```

But I am getting exception as

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/ghix-entity] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: could not locate named parameter [individualIds]] with root cause
org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: could not locate named parameter [individualIds]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.ParameterMetadata.getNamedParameterDescriptor(ParameterMetadata.java:101)
```

Comment: Any reason you are using a native query instead of a JPQL query which might support accepting a collection of parameters?

Answer (score 1):

Native queries do not recognize Named parameters. Please see below link seems like similar question: [JPA/Hibernate Native Queries do not recognize Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144235/jpa-hibernate-native-queries-do-not-recognize-parameters)

Try : 
`"SELECT I.INDIVIDUAL_CASE_ID,D.ASSISTER_ID,I.FIRSTNAME,I.LASTNAME,D.LAST_UPDATE_TIMESTAM‌​P,I.ELIGIBILITY_STATUS,I.INDIVIDUAL_CASE_ID," + "I.NUMBEROFHOUSEHOLDMEMBERS,I.HOUSEHOLD_INCOME FROM EXTERNAL_INDIVIDUAL I, EE_DESIGNATE_ASSISTERS D " + "WHERE I.INDIVIDUAL_CASE_ID = D.INDIVIDUAL_ID AND D.ASSISTER_ID=?1 AND D.INDIVIDUAL_ID IN (?2)";`

```
query = em.createNativeQuery(queryStr); 
query.setParameter(1, assisterId); 
query.setParameter(2,indvIdList);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Hibernate and not other JPA implementation than:

You can obtain the Hibernate Session from the entityManager:

```
Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
```

And then [you can use named parameters](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch18.html#d5e8463):

```
List result = 
    session.createSQLQuery(
            "SELECT I.INDIVIDUAL_CASE_ID,D.ASSISTER_ID,I.FIRSTNAME,I.LASTNAME,D.LAST_UPDATE_TIMESTAMP,I.ELIGIBILITY_STATUS,I.INDIVIDUAL_CASE_ID," +
                    "I.NUMBEROFHOUSEHOLDMEMBERS,I.HOUSEHOLD_INCOME FROM  EXTERNAL_INDIVIDUAL I, EE_DESIGNATE_ASSISTERS D " +
                    "WHERE I.INDIVIDUAL_CASE_ID = D.INDIVIDUAL_ID AND D.ASSISTER_ID=:assisterId AND D.INDIVIDUAL_ID IN (:individualIds)"
    )
    .setLong("assisterId", assisterId)
    .setParameterList("individualIds", indvIdList)
    .list();
```

Answer (score 0):

It was my issue. I was setting some extra parameters in the query object by mistake.After removing that the list is working fine.Thanks for all your suggestion