# Parameter in SELECT clause for @Query?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

While using a verbatim entered column name works fine in an SQL/JPA query, is it possible to use a variable?

```
@Query(value = "select distinct ?1 from Product", nativeQuery = true)
List<String> findOneColumn(String columnName);
```

This code appears to fail. It seems that it's not allowed to use parameters in SELECT clause (but works with WHERE clause). Is there any alternatives?

How can I set the column name dynamically?

Comment: What alternatives did you check? How far did you look for an existing answer? Is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144235/jpa-hibernate-native-queries-do-not-recognize-parameters related?

Comment: "appears to fail"? and the evidence of that is? an exception? And does JDBC allow a parameter in the SELECT clause?

Comment: the link doesn't solve this problem. And it seems that it's not allowed to use parameter in SELECT clause. Is there any alternatives? The main goal is dynamic selection of the column...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that Parameter in SELECT clause for @Query is not allowed pleasure :)

Comment: I also just had this issue, and could not find a solution - other than to build the query dynamically or hardcode the value in the SELECT