# JPA Query to select from DB

Tags: java, jpa, entitymanager

i have this method:

```
public List<String> getTipoConsensoRichiesto(String tipologiaProdotto) {
    return entityManager.createNativeQuery("Select TIPO_CONSENSO_RICHIESTO from  PRIVACY_CONFIGURAZIONE WHERE TIPOLOGIA_PRODOTTO = :tipologiaProdotto ")
        .setParameter("tipologiaProdotto",tipologiaProdotto)
        .getResultList();
}
```

when i execute the query i have the following problem:

> Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Parametro IN o OUT mancante
>   nell'indice:: 1 Error Code: 17041 Call: Select 
>   TIPO_CONSENSO_RICHIESTO from  PRIVACY_CONFIGURAZIONE WHERE
>   TIPOLOGIA_PRODOTTO = :tipologiaProdotto  Query:
>   DataReadQuery(sql="Select  TIPO_CONSENSO_RICHIESTO from 
>   PRIVACY_CONFIGURAZIONE WHERE TIPOLOGIA_PRODOTTO = :tipologiaProdotto
>   ")

How i can solve? 
Thank you

Comment: Named parameters are not mandatory to be supported in NATIVE queries in JPA, as per the JPA spec. Use numbered

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144235/jpa-hibernate-native-queries-do-not-recognize-parameters#3145275

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using:

`return entityManager.createNativeQuery("Select TIPO_CONSENSO_RICHIESTO from  PRIVACY_CONFIGURAZIONE WHERE TIPOLOGIA_PRODOTTO = ?1 ").setParameter(1,tipologiaProdotto).getResultList();`