# Hibernate simple select query doesn't return anything

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I got this simple Hibernate query set up but it returns nothing, here is my code:

```
      EntityManagerFactory emf = javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("timereg");
      EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

     int id = em.createQuery("SELECT emp.id FROM Employee as emp WHERE emp.bsn = '398723916'").getFirstResult();
     object.getEmployee().setId(id);
     System.out.println("query returns employee id: " + id);
```

The stupid thing is that id stays zero but when i execute this query in PostgreSQL it returns 37.

I think hibernate does not like my way of implementing a select query, does anyone know what is wrong with my select query ?

**THE ANSWER:**
There was nothing wrong with the select query i just had to use getSingeResult() instead of getFirstResult();
Change the code into:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("timereg");
      EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

     Object ob = em.createQuery("select id from Employee where bsn = '398723917'").getSingleResult();

        object.getEmployee().setId(Integer.parseInt(ob.toString()));
        System.out.println(ob);
```

This is the total solution for my problem, but i got inspired by Yanflea so he deserves all the credits.

Comment: Maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2110809/use-of-entitymanager-createnativequeryquery-foo-class) can help. i.e. try to use `BigDecimal` instead of `long`

Comment: thanks but i have already dropped the table and let it generate again with normal integers instead of long(Java)/bigint(SQL language). So the bigint in the table changed to int and the id in the employee class also changed to int.

ps. i updated my code

Comment: can you turn "Hibernate.SQL" in log4j on to see which sql is executed?

Comment: Hi @Firo and how do i do that ? (I'm new to Hibernate), when i do a local machine search on the term log4j i get loads of results... which logfile/settingfile should i pick ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with JPA, maybe these can help: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=984480  http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.express.doc%2Finfo%2Fexp%2Fae%2Ftejb_loggingwjpa.html

Comment: Thanks i found a way to check the database logs and it these select queries do get executed due to the fact that this will come into the logfile of the database:
2012-02-24 12:04:37 CET LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection

Comment: If you replace getFirstResult() by list() does it return anything useful?

Comment: I already tried that and it did not work :( thanks for you feedback though.

Comment: How can such a simple problem be such a pain in the ass..... :(

Comment: Have you tried using plain sql instead of hql? em.createSqlQuery(...)
See if that works so we can try to isolate the problem

Comment: FYI - to turn logging on in log4j just add this: log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG

Comment: @Andre ye i have tried to use createNativeQuery("select id from tbl_employee where bsn Like 'bsnnumber'") but that also did not work

Comment: @ndtreviv where do you want me to put that code?

Comment: in your log4j.properties file - are you using log4j?

Comment: @ndtreviv i have never heard of it so i dont think so, but i have already found the solution thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the method *getFirstResult()*, which gives you the position of the record in the table. You should use *getSingleResult()* instead. See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html.

**EDIT**

Here it is :

```
Object ob = em.createQuery("select id from Employee where bsn = '398723917'").getSingleResult();
```

Comment: getSingeResult() returns an object not a value.

Comment: You will have to cast it into the object you're expecting (BigInt or Integer, depending on your setup). Did you inspect it at all to see what object it returned?

Comment: In your other post -where you give your code-, id for the Employee class is a Long... So just cast the result into a Long...

Comment: ye that was old, i changed it to int. thanks for the notification iĺl edit the old post

Comment: @Yanflea Object test = em.createQuery("From Employee where bsn = '398723917'").getSingleResult();

        System.out.print(test.toString());
returns: com.jmonks.timereg.domain.Employee@670eab4

Comment: You must redefine .toString() in the Employee class if you want it to return your id property value. Otherwise it will just return the reference of the object.

Comment: Change your answer to: 
Object ob = em.createQuery("select id from Employee where bsn = '398723917'").getSingleResult();

then i will confirm it :D

Comment: Not sure to understand what you mean, but I guess you managed to make it work like you wanted to... :)

Comment: @Yanflea i will post the total answer in about 3 hours when i am allowed to answer on my own questions, then you have to copy that answer and edit it into yours then i will apply your answer so you get the credits.... I have also put the total answer on the bottom of the question.

Comment: Moved your final -and working- attempt in my answer, as you asked... :) The customer is king :).