# JPA Hibernate Postgres precision doesn't work

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa, entitymanager

I am trying to run query below ,`Postgres` database.

```
  select new map(avg(cast (speed as double precision)) as avg)
  from table
```

`speed` column is of type `varchar`

I am executing using JPA as below

```
        em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();        
        Query hqlQuery = em.createQuery(query);
        reportList = hqlQuery.getResultList();
```

When I run this I get error below

```
    Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting CLOSE, 
    found 'precision' near line 1
```

Has anyone come across this situation? Can I not use precision in Hibernate?

Comment: That looks like (mostly) SQL, not HQL. If you want to use Hibernate, you need to use the Hibernate query language, which has different type names, etc.

Comment: I am using Native SQL in Hibernate.

Comment: then you need to use createNativeQuery

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to execute native SQL in Hibernate via JPA, [you need to use `em.createNativeQuery`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2110860/398670).

`em.createQuery` expects an argument in JPQL, a query language derived from HQL, to the point where Hibernate's JPQL implementation uses the `org.hibernate.hql` classes.

That doesn't look like valid SQL either, though. `new map(...)` ? You can't mix JPQL/HQL, and I haven't seen `new` in an SQL dialect.

Answer (score 0):

I changed from

```
  select new map(avg(cast (speed as double precision)) as avg)
  from table
```

to

```
      select new map(avg(cast (speed as double)) as avg)
      from table
```

`Hibernate` supports that. I am still running as `HQL` query and it works.