# Database specific queries in a Spring Hibernate application

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

In a dao class implementation,I want to use different sql query  depending upon the underlying database. Since my SQL query is complex which selects from a database view and uses "UNION" key word and uses database specific functions, I can not use JPQL (or HQL). I did some search on Stackoverflow and threads suggest the good way would be to find out the dialect used in the application. Can anyone provide some code example?
EDIT : My apologies, I did not explain my question well enough. In my dao class implementation , I want to determine the database ( say mysql or oracle) on which my application is running and then execute the appropriate query. I need the code like jdbcTemplate.findOutTheDialect().

Answer (score 0):

JPA have the [native queries](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNativeQuery%28java.lang.String%29) for that.
An example you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2110809/use-of-entitymanager-createnativequeryquery-foo-class).

Comment: Thanks for responding. I just edited my question to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use spring JdbcTemplate to connect and query from your database.
For Example..

```
String query = "SELECT COUNTRY_NAME FROM COUNTRY WHERE MCC_COUNTRY NOT IN ('Reserved') ORDER BY COUNTRY_NAME";
jdbcTemplate.query(query, new ObjectRowMapper());
```

Where  "ObjectRowMapper" will be a class to map return resultset to list of Objects.