# methode JEE implementation

Tags: jpa

I implemented a method that allows me to generate a test ( entire of question ) automatically  but the problem is :
the method will obviously take the number of random questions but also the category of questions generated (I have a entié category and therefore a table too) I don't know where i will put the category in query.
and secondly RANDOM() is not taked by JPQL what can i do ?

[schema of the DataBase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUrW3.png)

```
public List<Question> prepareRandomTest(int number_of_questions, Categorie      categorie){ 
      String jpql = "SELECT q FROM Question q ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT "+number_of_questions  ;
     Query query = entityManager.createQuery(jpql);
      return query.getResultList();
    }
```

Comment: `entityManager.persist(Question.class);`?!

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin i correct it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use **Java Persistence Query Language here**, Hence your solution is not taking RANDOM into account. Use Native query and build Query from native sql string, Native query is just a plain sql statement without Entity object reference (like Question). This way a normal sql keywords like RANDOM etc are easily read.

[Native Query Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_native_sql.htm)
**Instead of Using**

```
String jpql = "SELECT q FROM Question q ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT "+number_of_questions  ;
```

**use:**

```
"SELECT * FROM question where category="+category+" ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT "+number_of_questions;
```

*Additional Advice:*
Get the category string from an "Enum" in your code to match the string value in the database category column.

Comment: in my program I use JPQL so it does not cause problem if I use simple SQL queries ?

Comment: Whether you are using JPQL or Sql Query String, hibernate will negotiate both on its own to create Query Object like this (Query query = entityManager.createQuery(jpql or sql);), so you dont have to worry about native query breaking your code, this is a mandatory abstraction hibernate provides.

Comment: is that correct?   public List<Question> prepareRandomTest(int number_of_questions, Categorie categorie){ 
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM question where category="+categorie+" ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT "+number_of_questions;
    SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);    
    List<Question> results = (List<Question>)query.list();
    return result;
  }

Comment: "return results"  instead of returning result.

Comment: SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql); sqlQuery can not be resolved as a type and session also can you help me

Comment: can you paste the whole stacktrace, what is sqlQuery object?

Comment: public List<Question> prepareRandomTest(int number_of_questions, Categorie categorie){ 
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM question where category="+categorie+" ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT "+number_of_questions;
    SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql); =>sqlquery and session can not be resolved as a type   
    List<Question> results = (List<Question>)query.list();
    return results;
  }

Comment: Oh yeah you dont have Session Object defined as you are using EntityManager, you need to pull out Session from EntityManager...Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);

Comment: If you dont want to use Session, and wish to use EntityManage itself, than use, this solution, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2110809/use-of-entitymanager-createnativequeryquery-foo-class

Comment: the last solution is not compatible with my exemple sorry