# Create native SQL query without creating entity class in SpringBoot

Tags: sql, spring, spring-boot, orm, hibernate-mapping

The fundamental of ORM is mapping with the objects. But, for some reason, I don't want to create objects for running a query.

Is there any way, in which without creating entities (managed classes), I can run a native SQL query?

Comment: possible duplication? https://stackoverflow.com/a/2110860/672798

Answer (score 4):

Yes. You can.

Create a method in the repository class with specific query (native query):

```
@Query(value="select * from emp", nativeQuery=true)
Object getAllFromEmp();
```

Keep this method in the repository interface and call it from the service class

Or you can use **EntityManager** object as below

```
Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM emp e");
List<Object[]> empObject= q.getResultList();
```

Comment: But, here I need to have a class of 'emp' and make it as an entity, else if not, it is throwing error. I don't want to create an 'emp' class( managed class ), or to better say, I don't want to use ORM for some use-case. I am designing reporting services and for that, I don't want to create class(managed entities) for every report

Comment: here **emp** is table name not class name and we are using **native query** not **HQL** here.

Comment: do i need to implement all the methods of javax.persistance.EntityManager?

Comment: @aarushgandhi73 no need to implement all the methods, create a entityManager object and used pre-defined methods

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at `createNativeQuery`

```
...
Query query = em.createNativeQuery("select ...");
...
```

And, I think you can find more about it in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2110860/672798