# Do we need to write entity class for each and every table in spring boot?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

I have the following requirement:

Modify the Spring boot application MovieMax of Exercise 1 to use Spring Data JPA so that the data is persisted in the MySQL DB.

Fetch the theater details from theater table and movie details from movie table.

Booking a movie should update corresponding details in theatermovieshow table and booking table

The following script can be used for creation of the tables:

create table user(userid varchar(8) primary key, username varchar(25), password varchar(10), emailid varchar(30), phone int);

create table theater(theaterid varchar(8) primary key, theatername varchar(30), seatsavailable int(3), city varchar(25));

create table movie(movieid varchar(8) primary key, moviename varchar(40), language varchar(15), category varchar(20), islive boolean);

create table theatermovieshow( showid varchar(8) primary key,

theaterid varchar(8) references theater(theaterid),

movieid varchar(8) references movie(movieid),

showtime varchar(8),

startdate date,

enddate date,

ticketrate double(6,2));

create table booking(bookingid int(5), userid varchar(8) references user(userid),

showid varchar(8) references theatermovieshow(showid),

noofseats int,

amountpaid double(8,2),

showdate date,

bookingdate date);

Verification:

On execution, the required details should be fetched from database.

Verify that booking details are getting persisted in corresponding tables.

***Do I need to write entity classes for each and every table? I am using spring Boot***

Comment: Is 4 classes too much?

Comment: You don't. Just use native query and read the result.

Comment: Why are you using Spring Boot?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create classes for every table. You can use native query.
Quoting answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/50956683/1039555 :-

> Create a method in the repository class with specific query (native
>   query):
>
> ```
> @Query(value="select * from emp", nativeQuery=true)
> Object getAllFromEmp();
> ```
>
> Keep this method in the repository interface and call it from the
>   service class
>
> Or you can use `EntityManager` object as below
>
> ```
> Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM emp e");
> List<Object[]> empObject= q.getResultList();
> ```

For updates, use a method like `executeUpdate()`.